# object reference is not set to an instance, but the class is static

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am struggling with this problem for quite a while now:
I have this static class:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Platformer;
{
    public static class VarBoard
    {
        public static GameObject Player;
        public static GameObject LevelGenerator;
        public static GameObject PlayerHealthBar;
        public static List <GameObject> AllEnemies = new List<GameObject> ();
        public static List <GameObject> AllFriends = new List<GameObject> ();
    }
}
```

This class stores all global Variables, so I can use them from various places in my project, like this:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using Platformer;

public class HealthBar : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Update{
        this.GetComponent<RectTransform> ().sizeDelta = new Vector2 (VarBoard.Player.GetComponent<Character> ().health, 40);
    }
}
```

I found this structure in [this](http://stormtek.geek.nz/rts_tutorial/part2.php) tutorial and it seemed to be a reasonable solution for me, but when I run the code I just get this

> Exception: NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

But as far as I understand, isn't it the purpose of a static class that you don't need instances of it? 
Or am I missing something here?

Comment: Check this part of the code new Vector2 (VarBoard.Player.GetComponent<Character> ().health, 40); 
Player needs to be initialized before using it.

Comment: Sriram, this isn't a duplicate of that, the op isn't asking how to fix the issue, but instead, do you need an instance for a static member

Comment: The `VarBoard.Player` is null, you need to initialize`Player`

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialise the static class object (the singleton) by way of its constructor.

```
public static class GameItemService
{
    // We don't have a database, just a singleton
    public static List<GameItem> LIST_OF_GAME_ITEMS; // A singleton for add/retrieve data


    static GameItemService()
    {
        LIST_OF_GAME_ITEMS= new List<GameItem>();
        // Add to the list here
    }
```

And then you can use the singleton e.g.

```
var items = GameItemService.LIST_OF_GAME_ITEMS.Take(20);
```

or similar.

Does that help?

Comment: Not sure if "singleton" is the correct word here. A `static` property (or class) does not specifically have to be a singleton. I'd replace it with "property". Rest of the answer is correct though.

Answer (score 0):

They still need to point to something in memory

As stated on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/98f28cdx.aspx)

> "Use the static modifier to declare a static member, which belongs to the type itself rather than to a specific object."